# Is it possible to start/stop a Falcor (NodeJS) app through its Sidecar Java Spring service?

Tags: java, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, falcor

I am setting up a test Java Spring environment using Netflix OSS software. Included in this I have the Eureka Discovery server, a basic test microservice and a Sidecar service that connects to a Falcor NodeJS service.

These services will need to be started/stopped by a deployment system that only knows how to kill Java apps. Is it possible to kill the NodeJS app through the Sidecar instance? If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The sidecar is not designed to start or stop processes. It is only there to register one, and provide health checks etc. You will need some other supervisor-type system to manage the lifecycle of your apps.

Comment: That makes sense. Just to clarify my understanding...should the sidecar to manage any app data interactions at all (e.g. moving data between Falcor and other Java microservices), or should additional APIs be built for that purpose?

Comment: The sidecar is meant to register the non java service with eureka and provide an outbound proxy. All incoming traffic goes directly to the non java service.